Shift the Conda environment from base to my created environment, which isn't working
I used Conda to shift my virtual environment from base to python_course using Conda. It doesn't work at all.
I want to shift my virtual environment from base to newly created environment python_course in VS Code using Conda.
Please refer to the image for problem.
Please help me.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

there is no Image to be seen. Do you want to rename your environment?
That is as easy as:
conda rename --name base python_course 

If you want to create a copy with a new name
conda create --name pyhton_course--clone base

